# how can I implement a slow smooth background scrolling in sdl

Tags: scroll, bitmap, sdl

I am trying to implement background scrolling using SDL 2.
As far as I understand one can only move source rectangle by an integer value.
My scrolling works fine when I move it by one every iteration of the game loop.
But I want to move it slower. I tried to move it using this code

```
    moved += speed;
    if (moved >= 1.0) {
        ++src_rect.x;
        moved -= 1;
    }
```

Here `moved` and `speed` are `double`s . I want my background to move something like ten times slower, therefore I set `speed` to `0.1`. It does move ten times slower, but the animation is no longer smooth. It kind of jumps from one pixel to another, which looks and feels ugly when the speed is low.

I am thinking of making my background larger and scrolling it using an integer. Maybe when background is large enough the speed of `1` will seem slower.

Is there a way to scroll not a very large background slowly and smoothly and the same time?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried to scroll the background by `1` and tiles by `5`. The background motion does look slow and smooth when tiles move five times faster in front of it. Perhaps just making background little larger and to scroll it by `1` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is have a set of floats that would track the virtual screen position, then you just cast the floats to integers when you actually render, that way you don't ever lose the precision of the floats.

To give you an example, I have an SDL_Rect, I want to move it every frame. I have two floating point variables that track the x and y position of the rect, every frame I would update those x and y positions, cast them to an integer, and then render the rect, EX:

```
   // Rect position 
   float XPos = 0.0f; 
   float YPos = 0.0f;

   SDL_Rect rect = {0, 0, 64, 64}; 

   // Update virtual positions
   XPos += 20.0f * DeltaTime; 
   YPos += 20.0f * DeltaTime; 

   // Move rect down and to the right 
   rect.x = (int)XPos; 
   rect.y = (int)YPos;
```

While this doesn't give you the exact result you are wanting, it is the only way that I know of to do this, it will let you delay your movement more precisely without giving you that ugly chunkiness in the movement, it also will let you add stuff like more precise acceleration too. Hope this helps.

Comment: I just tried your code. Perhaps your code is better than mine, but the animation is still like trembling, because when the speed is `float` every iteration the displacement distance will be different. Therefore float scrolling will not be smooth.

Comment: To fix that you may consider doing an add, mine does that because it multiplies the position each frame, try adding a flat float and see what you get.